# Python detect x server error when showing image

Tags: python, linux, ssh, python-imaging-library

Is there any way of catching an X server exception in Python when using Image.show()?

When I try to show an image over an ssh connection when I haven't used the `-X` or `-Y` option, I want to stop running the program, since this will be running in a loop so there's no point in trying to load more images.
This displays the error `display.im6: unable to open X server ' @ error/display.c/DisplayImageCommand/428.'`
But it doesn't seem possible to catch this since I think the OS is showing this error after the PIL Image.show() call is performed.

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open(img_name)
try:
    img.show()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    sys.exit()
```

The call never goes into the except call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As can be seen from PIL's code at https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.3.x/_modules/PIL/ImageShow.html , the `show` method in images will ultimately call `os.system` with a heuristically determined command to display the image. The problem, as can be seen here, is, that the return value of the `os.system` call is ignored, so, even when the image is not displayed, the program will never know that.

You could try monkey-patching `os.system` to raise an error if the original os.system returns anything other than zero, and then you'd have an exception.
However, upon attempting it this way, I noticed that for my default viewer, it returns "0" as exit code anyway, even with a broken display, so it is not detectable with "system". You'd have to monkeypatch `os.system` with a function that would make a proper `subprocess.Popen` call and check not only the exit-code, but also the `sdterr` of the called command - it's starting to get tricky.

So, a second, simpler, and possibly safer route, is to have your program check the contents of the `DISPLAY` environment variable. If it is empty or invalid, any attempt to use the X display will fail:

```
import os

if not os.environ.get("DISPLAY"):
    raise RuntimeError("Display is not properly set. Aborting!")
```

**Why is it that way?** Historically PIL's (the original PIL, not the currently maintained Pillow) `show` code was a simple, hardcoded call to `xv` - it was probably found to be only useful for debugging purposes by the original library owners. Although today it is more sophisticated, looking for a suitable external viewer among a couple of (still hardcoded) options, is not a "first class UI" in any way. I think it is proper for your described use-case, but for anything beyond that, maybe the first option would be to move to `matplotlib` to display the images in a UI which is better controlled from the Python code, without having to resort to write full GUI code with Qt or Tkinter.

Comment: Great, it's as I thought, thanks for trying it!  
Also, your code should be `if "DISPLAY" not in os.environ:` since there will be a KeyError if you try to access it directly

Comment: Thanks for adding the explanation at the end too. Another alternative is to use OpenCV's image display capabilities